# How do I sort a std::vector by the values of a different std::vector?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, vector, sorting

I have several `std::vector`, all of the same length. I want to sort one of these vectors, and apply the same transformation to all of the other vectors.  Is there a neat way of doing this? (preferably using the STL or Boost)?  Some of the vectors hold `int`s and some of them `std::string`s.

Pseudo code:

```
std::vector<int> Index = { 3, 1, 2 };
std::vector<std::string> Values = { "Third", "First", "Second" };

Transformation = sort(Index);
Index is now { 1, 2, 3};

... magic happens as Transformation is applied to Values ...
Values are now { "First", "Second", "Third" };
```

Comment: I agree with both answers, if you are going to do this more than once though you might as well make the array that you sort carry the index values from the start or even create a class that carries all the data that you now have in multiple vectors and sort all of the data at once.

Comment: I know, it is 2015, but I find this to be a super-elegant and easy-to-implement solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17554242/3093378 It is actually similar to the accepted answer, but a bit simpler imo, so one can implement a `custom_sort` that returns a `std::vector<std::size_t>` of indexes, similar to MATLAB.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

friol's approach is good when coupled with yours. First, build a vector consisting of the numbers 1…*n*, along with the elements from the vector dictating the sorting order:

```
typedef vector<int>::const_iterator myiter;

vector<pair<size_t, myiter> > order(Index.size());

size_t n = 0;
for (myiter it = Index.begin(); it != Index.end(); ++it, ++n)
    order[n] = make_pair(n, it);
```

Now you can sort this array using a custom sorter:

```
struct ordering {
    bool operator ()(pair<size_t, myiter> const& a, pair<size_t, myiter> const& b) {
        return *(a.second) < *(b.second);
    }
};

sort(order.begin(), order.end(), ordering());
```

Now you've captured the order of rearrangement inside `order` (more precisely, in the first component of the items). You can now use this ordering to sort your other vectors. There's probably a very clever in-place variant running in the same time, but until someone else comes up with it, here's one variant that isn't in-place. It uses `order` as a look-up table for the new index of each element.

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> sort_from_ref(
    vector<T> const& in,
    vector<pair<size_t, myiter> > const& reference
) {
    vector<T> ret(in.size());

    size_t const size = in.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        ret[i] = in[reference[i].first];

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the sort of solution I had in mind, I was just wondering if there was some nice way of applying the same transformation to several  vectors, but I guess not.

Answer (score 10):

```
typedef std::vector<int> int_vec_t;
typedef std::vector<std::string> str_vec_t;
typedef std::vector<size_t> index_vec_t;

class SequenceGen {
  public:
    SequenceGen (int start = 0) : current(start) { }
    int operator() () { return current++; }
  private:
    int current;
};

class Comp{
    int_vec_t& _v;
  public:
    Comp(int_vec_t& v) : _v(v) {}
    bool operator()(size_t i, size_t j){
         return _v[i] < _v[j];
   }
};

index_vec_t indices(3);
std::generate(indices.begin(), indices.end(), SequenceGen(0));
//indices are {0, 1, 2}

int_vec_t Index = { 3, 1, 2 };
str_vec_t Values = { "Third", "First", "Second" };

std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), Comp(Index));
//now indices are {1,2,0}
```

Now you can use the "indices" vector to index into "Values" vector.

Answer (score 8):

Put your values in a [Boost Multi-Index container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) then iterate over to read the values in the order you want. You can even copy them to another vector if you want to.

Answer (score 4):

Only one rough solution comes to my mind: create a vector that is the sum of all other vectors (a vector of structures, like {3,Third,...},{1,First,...}) then sort this vector by the first field, and then split the structures again.

Probably there is a better solution inside Boost or using the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably define a custom "facade" iterator that does what you need here. It would store iterators to all your vectors or alternatively derive the iterators for all but the first vector from the offset of the first. The tricky part is what that iterator dereferences to: think of something like boost::tuple and make clever use of boost::tie. (If you wanna extend on this idea, you can build these iterator types recursively using templates but you probably never want to write down the type of that - so you either need c++0x auto or a wrapper function for sort that takes ranges)

Comment: For example http://www.stanford.edu/~dgleich/notebook/2006/03/sorting_two_arrays_simultaneou.html

Answer (score 3):

I think what you *really* need (but correct me if I'm wrong) is a way to access elements of a container in some order.

Rather than rearranging my original collection, I would borrow a concept from Database design:  keep an index, ordered by a certain criterion.  This index is an extra indirection that offers great flexibility.

This way it is possible to generate multiple indices according to different members of a class.

```
using namespace std;

template< typename Iterator, typename Comparator >
struct Index {
    vector<Iterator> v;

    Index( Iterator from, Iterator end, Comparator& c ){
        v.reserve( std::distance(from,end) );
        for( ; from != end; ++from ){
            v.push_back(from); // no deref!
        }
        sort( v.begin(), v.end(), c );
    }

};

template< typename Iterator, typename Comparator >
Index<Iterator,Comparator> index ( Iterator from, Iterator end, Comparator& c ){
    return Index<Iterator,Comparator>(from,end,c);
}

struct mytype {
    string name;
    double number;
};

template< typename Iter >
struct NameLess : public binary_function<Iter, Iter, bool> {
    bool operator()( const Iter& t1, const Iter& t2 ) const { return t1->name < t2->name; }
};

template< typename Iter >
struct NumLess : public binary_function<Iter, Iter, bool> {
    bool operator()( const Iter& t1, const Iter& t2 ) const { return t1->number < t2->number; }
};

void indices() {

    mytype v[] =    { { "me"    ,  0.0 }
                    , { "you"   ,  1.0 }
                    , { "them"  , -1.0 }
                    };
    mytype* vend = v + _countof(v);

    Index<mytype*, NameLess<mytype*> > byname( v, vend, NameLess<mytype*>() );
    Index<mytype*, NumLess <mytype*> > bynum ( v, vend, NumLess <mytype*>() );

    assert( byname.v[0] == v+0 );
    assert( byname.v[1] == v+2 );
    assert( byname.v[2] == v+1 );

    assert( bynum.v[0] == v+2 );
    assert( bynum.v[1] == v+0 );
    assert( bynum.v[2] == v+1 );

}
```

Comment: Boost provides this functionality http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting, but if I read it right it's not what I was looking for - I want one index to apply to several vectors, rather than several different indexes.  I think Konrad Rudolph and friol's approaches give me the result I was looking for, but I was hoping for something a bit cleaner

Comment: What's the purpouse of inheriting from `binary_function<T,T, bool>`, is it possible to use NameLess without inheriting form `binary_function`?

Comment: It totally is; with C++11 lot of this became way easier!

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more compact variant of xtofl's answer for if you are just looking to iterate through all your vectors based on the  of a single `keys` vector. Create a permutation vector and use this to index into your other vectors.

```
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<double> keys = ...
std::vector<double> values = ...

std::vector<size_t> indices(boost::counting_iterator<size_t>(0u), boost::counting_iterator<size_t>(keys.size()));
std::sort(begin(indices), end(indices), [&](size_t lhs, size_t rhs) {
    return keys[lhs] < keys[rhs];
});

// Now to iterate through the values array.
for (size_t i: indices)
{
    std::cout << values[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ltjax's answer is a great approach - which is actually implemented in boost's zip_iterator http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html

It packages together into a tuple whatever iterators you provide it.

You can then create your own comparison function for a sort based on any combination of iterator values in your tuple. For this question, it would just be the first iterator in your tuple.

A nice feature of this approach is that it allows you to keep the memory of each individual vector contiguous (if you're using vectors and that's what you want). You also don't need to store a separate index vector of ints.

Comment: Actually my apologies, I need to amend my answer. boost::zip_iterator doesn't seem to support std:sort. But Anthony Williams made a modification to it called TupleIt that does work with sort. See this post on the boost mailing list: [link](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2004/07/68876.php). The iterator code can be found on the boost yahoo group under tupleit.zip.

Answer (score 1):

This would have been an addendum to Konrad's answer as it an approach for a in-place variant of applying the sort order to a vector. Anyhow since the edit won't go through I will put it here

Here is a in-place variant with a slightly higher time complexity that is due to a primitive operation of checking a boolean. The additional space complexity is of a vector which can be a space efficient compiler dependent implementation. The complexity of a vector can be eliminated if the given order itself can be modified.

Here is a in-place variant with a slightly higher time complexity that is due to a primitive operation of checking a boolean. The additional space complexity is of a vector which can be a space efficient compiler dependent implementation. The complexity of a vector can be eliminated if the given order itself can be modified. This is a example of what the algorithm is doing. 
If the order is   3 0 4 1 2, the movement of the elements as indicated by the position indices would be 3--->0; 0--->1; 1--->3; 2--->4; 4--->2.

```
template<typename T>
struct applyOrderinPlace
{
void operator()(const vector<size_t>& order, vector<T>& vectoOrder)
{
vector<bool> indicator(order.size(),0);
size_t start = 0, cur = 0, next = order[cur];
size_t indx = 0;
T tmp; 

while(indx < order.size())
{
//find unprocessed index
if(indicator[indx])
{   
++indx;
continue;
}

start = indx;
cur = start;
next = order[cur];
tmp = vectoOrder[start];

while(next != start)
{
vectoOrder[cur] = vectoOrder[next];
indicator[cur] = true; 
cur = next;
next = order[next];
}
vectoOrder[cur] = tmp;
indicator[cur] = true;
}
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively simple implementation using *index mapping* between the ordered and unordered `names` that will be used to match the `ages` to the ordered `names`:

```
void ordered_pairs()
{
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::vector<int> ages;

    // read input and populate the vectors
    populate(names, ages);

    // print input
    print(names, ages);

    // sort pairs
    std::vector<std::string> sortedNames(names);
    std::sort(sortedNames.begin(), sortedNames.end());

    std::vector<int> indexMap;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sortedNames.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < names.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (sortedNames[i] == names[j]) 
            {
                indexMap.push_back(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // use the index mapping to match the ages to the names
    std::vector<int> sortedAges;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < indexMap.size(); ++i)
    {
        sortedAges.push_back(ages[indexMap[i]]);
    }

    std::cout << "Ordered pairs:\n";
    print(sortedNames, sortedAges); 
}
```

For the sake of completeness, here are the functions `populate()` and `print()`:

```
void populate(std::vector<std::string>& n, std::vector<int>& a)
{
    std::string prompt("Type name and age, separated by white space; 'q' to exit.\n>>");
    std::string sentinel = "q";

    while (true)
    {
        // read input
        std::cout << prompt;
        std::string input;
        getline(std::cin, input);

        // exit input loop
        if (input == sentinel)
        {
            break;
        }

        std::stringstream ss(input);

        // extract input
        std::string name;
        int age;
        if (ss >> name >> age)
        {
            n.push_back(name);
            a.push_back(age);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout <<"Wrong input format!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
void print(const std::vector<std::string>& n, const std::vector<int>& a)
{
    if (n.size() != a.size())
    {
        std::cerr <<"Different number of names and ages!\n";
        return;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n.size(); ++i)
    {
         std::cout <<'(' << n[i] << ", " << a[i] << ')' << "\n";
    }
}
```

And finally, `main()` becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void ordered_pairs();
void populate(std::vector<std::string>&, std::vector<int>&);
void print(const std::vector<std::string>&, const std::vector<int>&);

//=======================================================================
int main()
{
    std::cout << "\t\tSimple name - age sorting.\n";
    ordered_pairs();
}
//=======================================================================
// Function Definitions...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**// C++ program to demonstrate sorting in vector
// of pair according to 2nd element of pair
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// Driver function to sort the vector elements
// by second element of pairs
bool sortbysec(const pair<char,char> &a,
              const pair<int,int> &b)
{
    return (a.second < b.second);
}

int main()
{
    // declaring vector of pairs
    vector< pair <char, int> > vect;

    // Initialising 1st and 2nd element of pairs
    // with array values
    //int arr[] = {10, 20, 5, 40 };
    //int arr1[] = {30, 60, 20, 50};
    char arr[] = { ' a', 'b', 'c' };
    int arr1[] = { 4, 7, 1 };

    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    // Entering values in vector of pairs
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        vect.push_back( make_pair(arr[i],arr1[i]) );

    // Printing the original vector(before sort())
    cout << "The vector before sort operation is:\n" ;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        // "first" and "second" are used to access
        // 1st and 2nd element of pair respectively
        cout << vect[i].first << " "
             << vect[i].second << endl;

    }

    // Using sort() function to sort by 2nd element
    // of pair
    sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), sortbysec);

    // Printing the sorted vector(after using sort())
    cout << "The vector after sort operation is:\n" ;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        // "first" and "second" are used to access
        // 1st and 2nd element of pair respectively
        cout << vect[i].first << " "
             << vect[i].second << endl;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;`enter code here`
}**
```

Comment: This is my solution for sorting second container based on first container.

Answer (score 0):

with C++11 lambdas and the STL algorithms based on answers from Konrad Rudolph and Gabriele D'Antona:

```
template< typename T, typename U >
std::vector<T> sortVecAByVecB( std::vector<T> & a, std::vector<U> & b ){

    // zip the two vectors (A,B)
    std::vector<std::pair<T,U>> zipped(a.size());
    for( size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) zipped[i] = std::make_pair( a[i], b[i] );

    // sort according to B
    std::sort(zipped.begin(), zipped.end(), []( auto & lop, auto & rop ) { return lop.second < rop.second; }); 

    // extract sorted A
    std::vector<T> sorted;
    std::transform(zipped.begin(), zipped.end(), std::back_inserter(sorted), []( auto & pair ){ return pair.first; }); 

    return sorted;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

So many asked this question and nobody came up with a satisfactory answer. Here is a std::sort helper that enables to sort two vectors simultaneously, taking into account the values of only one vector. This solution is based on a custom RadomIt (random iterator), and operates directly on the original vector data, without temporary copies, structure rearrangement or additional indices:

[C++, Sort One Vector Based On Another One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368787/c-sort-one-vector-based-on-another-one/46370189#46370189)