# Sorting Of two arrays

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

Suppose I have been given two array.For ex- Process With their Arrival Time and Finish Time.
I want to sort it on the basis of finish time.On the basis of Finish Time,Arrival Time Should also be sorted.
I can use bubble sort or selection sort for this purpose.
But Is there any STL for this purpose?
Can I use sort() function with some modifications?

Comment: You'll want to use a stable sort routine: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability. Also, show some code or at least pseudo-code.

Comment: possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909272/sorting-two-corresponding-arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a vector of (end, start) pairs (in this order - explanation below), sort it, then split the pairs of the sorted output:

```
#include <utility> // For pair
#include <algorithm> // For sort

std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> intervals;
for(size_t i = 0; i < start.size(); ++i)
    intervals.push_back(std::make_pair(end[i], start[i]));

std::sort(std::begin(intervals), std::end(intervals)); // (*)

start.clear();
end.clear();
for(size_t i = 0; i < start.size(); ++i)
{
    end[i] = intervals[i].first;
    start[i] = intervals[i].second;
}
```

Note the line with the `(*)` comment. [STL pairs' order is lexicographic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819245/is-stdpairint-stdstring-ordering-well-defined), which we exploit here (sorting pairs will sort by the `first`s for free).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a functor to `std::sort` or provide `operator <` for your data:

```
struct MyClass
{
    std::size_t arrivalTime;
    std::size_t finishTime;
};

std::vector<MyClass> myClasses = //..
std::sort(myClasses .begin(), myClasses.end(),
          [](const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
              return std::tie(lhs.finishTime, lhs.arrivalTime)
                     < std::tie(rhs.finishTime, rhs.arrivalTime);
         });
```

or simply

```
bool operator< (const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.finishTime, lhs.arrivalTime)
           < std::tie(rhs.finishTime, rhs.arrivalTime);
}
```

and later:

```
std::sort(myClasses .begin(), myClasses.end());
```