# Arranging by indexes vector

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have two vectors: a vector and index vector. How can I make the vector be arranged by the indexes vector? Like:

```
Indexes                5 0 2 1 3 4
Values                 a b c d e f
Values after operation b d c e f a
```

The indexes vector will always contain the range `[0, n)` and each index only once.
I need this operation to be done in place because the code is going to be run on a device with low memory.
How can I do this in c++? I can use c++11

Comment: have you considered [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/236172/1025391)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<int>  indices = { 5,   0,   2,   1,   3,   4};
std::vector<char> values  = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

for(size_t n = 0; n < indices.size(); ++n)
{
    while(indices[n] != n)
    {
        std::swap(values[n],  values[indices[n]]);
        std::swap(indices[n], indices[indices[n]]);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I think this should be O(n), anyone disagree?

Answer (score 3):

Since you know that your index array is a permutation of `[0, N)`, you can do this in linear time and in-place (plus *one* temporary) by working cycle-by-cycle. Something like this:

```
size_t indices[N];
data_t values[N];

for (size_t pos = 0; pos < N; ++pos)  // \
{                                     //  }  this loops _over_ cycles
  if (indices[pos] == pos) continue;  // /

  size_t i = pos;
  const data_t tmp = values[pos];

  while (true)                        // --> this loops _through_ one cycle
  {
    const size_t next = indices[i];
    indices[i] = i;
    values[i] = values[next];

    if (next == pos) break;
    i = next;
  }

  values[i] = tmp;
}
```

This implementation has the advantage over using `swap` each time that we only need to use the temporary variable *once per cycle*.

If the data type is move-only, this still works if all the assignments are surrounded by `std::move()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<=indexes.size();++i)
 for(int j=i+1;j<=indexes.size();++j)
             if(indexes[i] > indexes[j] )
                       swap(indexes[i],indexes[j]),
                       swap(values[i],values[j]);
```

It's O(N²) complexity, but should work fine on small number values.

You can also pass a comparison function to the C++ STL sort function if you want O(N*logN)

Answer (score 0):

You can just sort the vector, your comparison operation should compare the indices. Of course, when moving the data around, you have to move the indices, too.

At the end, your indices will be just 0, 1, ... (n-1), and the data will be at the corresponding places.

As implementation note: you can store the values and indices together in a structure:

```
struct SortEntry
{
    Data value;
    size_t index;
};
```

and define the comparison operator to look only at indices:

```
bool operator< (const SortEntry& lhs, const SortEntry& rhs)
{
    return lhs.index < rhs.index;
}
```

Comment: There is the problem that the comparison operator gives only values, not their index

Comment: But then I will need to copy the data to sort entry

Comment: Well, you have two ways: (1) make your data to be in the appropriate structure at the very beginning; (2) make your code sort just the indices, and when moving an index as a part of your sorting procedure, move the appropriate data, too.

Answer (score 0):

This solution runs in O(n) time:

```
int tmp;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  while(indexes[i] != i){
    swap(values[i], values[indexes[i]]);
    tmp = indexes[i];
    swap(indexes[i], indexes[tmp]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will run in O(n) time without any error.Check it on [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int indexes[6]={2,3,5,1,0,4};
char values[6]={'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
int result[sizeof(indexes)/4];          //creating array of size indexes or values
int a,i;
for( i=0;i<(sizeof(indexes)/4);i++)
{
    a=indexes[i];                       //saving the index value at i of array indexes
    result[a]=values[i];                //saving the result in result array
 }
 for ( i=0;i<(sizeof(indexes)/4);i++)
   printf("%c",result[i]);              //printing the result
   system("PAUSE"); 
   return 0;
}
```