# C++ Parallel std::vector Sorting With Expensive Copying

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

Assume I have a `vector<int>` `intVec` and a `vector<vector<double> >` `matrix`.  I want to sort `intVec` and reorder the first dimension of `matrix` correspondingly in C++.  I realize this question has been asked several times before, but this case has a twist.  A `vector<double>` is expensive to copy, so e.g. copying both `intVec` and `matrix` to a `vector<pair<int, vector<double> >`, sorting that and copying them back is even more inefficient than usual.

Short of rolling my own custom sorting algorithm, how can I sort `intVec` and reorder the first dimension of `matrix` in lockstep *without copying any element of `matrix` and invoking `vector`'s copy constructor*?

Comment: u now, the solution to any cs problem is another layer of indirection

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a std::vector by the values of a different std::vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236172/how-do-i-sort-a-stdvector-by-the-values-of-a-different-stdvector)

Comment: Yes, like Alf says, use a different way to store/access your vector<double>, so that you don't need to copy it - rolling your own function obviously won't solve the issue. Using a `vector<*vector<double>>` for example will work [you can still have a normal `vector<vector<double>>` and just initialize the first vector with the addresses of the elements in the second one.

Comment: @Mats: What is a `vector<*vector<double>>`?

Comment: The correct syntax is `vector<vector<double>*>`  - at least, that compiles, I didn't try to fill the vector with anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A `vector<double>` is expensive to copy, so e.g. copying both intVec and
>   matrix to a `vector<pair<int, vector<double> >`, sorting that and
>   copying them back is even more inefficient than usual.

The simplest way to get the optimization you want then is to *swap* the elements of the source `vector<vector<double>>` into the temporary `vector<pair<int, vector<double>>`, sort it, and then *swap* them back to their new locations in the original vector.

There will still be more overhead than is strictly necessary (for example to construct and destroy empty vectors). However, no vector is ever copied and the code remains very similar to what you already have. So if you are correct that the problem is the cost of copying, problem solved.

In C++11 you could move in both directions rather than swapping. I doubt there's much performance difference between moving and swapping with an empty vector, but I'm not sure there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the space between your two `>`'s, I'm guessing you're using pre-C++11 C++.  In C++11, `std::sort` seems to move elements whenever possible instead of copying.

You can pass a custom comparator to `std::sort`.  However, even if you do this, you're doing Theta(n log n) copies of `pair<int, vector<double> >`'s.

I'd guess, based on not actually trying it, that you should sort a `pair<int, vector<double> *>` (or `pair<int, int>` if `int` is big enough), using the second `int` as an index) instead to get the appropriate permutation and then apply the permutation using `vector`'s `swap` member function to avoid copying the vector contents.

Answer (score 1):

One option: create a `std::vector<std::pair<int,size_t>>` where the first element is the int from intVec and the second element is the original index of that element.  Then sort that new vector.  Then shuffle your matrix and intVec to the order indicated by the second elements of the pairs (e.g., with a single pass, doing swaps).

Comment: Beware that the "shuffle" stage isn't entirely trivial. Simply swapping each element in turn with its proper destination doesn't work.

Comment: To make the shuffle stage trivial use swap to move, and create an empty vector of vector of double.  Resize this temp vector to have empty vector of doubles. Swap to move directly to the right spot.  Then swap the temp with the original.  This ends up mostly just moving pointers around.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to copy the `vector<double>` item vector, then make a vector of pointer or indices to the `vector<double>` items. Sort it along with the main vector.

It is however not at all clear that you'll get a performance gain, and so I suggest that you **measure** both the straightforward sorting and the smart sorting, and compare.

---

Example:

```
#include    <algorithm>
#include    <vector>
#include    <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Mat
{
    vector< vector< double > >  items;

    Mat( int const size )
        : items( size, vector< double >( size ) )
    {}
};

struct KeyAndData
{
    int                     key;
    vector< double > const* data;

    friend bool operator<( KeyAndData const& a, KeyAndData const& b )
    {
        return a.key < b.key;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int const       data[]  = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5};
    Mat             m( 5 );
    vector<int>     v( 5 );

    for( int i = 0;  i < 5;  ++i )
    {
        m.items[i][i] = v[i] = data[i];
    }

    vector< KeyAndData >        sorted( 5 );
    for( int i = 0;  i < 5;  ++i )
    {
        sorted[i].key = v[i];
        sorted[i].data = &m.items[i];
    }

    sort( sorted.begin(), sorted.end() );
    for( int i = 0;  i < 5;  ++i )
    {
        cout << sorted[i].key << ":  ";

        vector< double > const& r = *sorted[i].data;
        for( int x = 0;  x < 5;  ++x )
        {
            cout << r[x] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to restructure your two vectors as one `vector<pair<int, vector<double> >` (since the data are clearly tightly coupled aready).

If that's really not an option then create another vector of indexes and sort that instead of the vec and matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`std::vector::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) operates in constant time, you could use a sorting algorithm that operates via a series of swaps (like quicksort) to sort `intVec` while simultaneously performing identical swaps on `matrix`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// Sorts intVec in [low, high) while also performing identical swaps on matrix.
void iqsort(std::vector<int> &intVec, std::vector<std::vector<double>> &matrix,
            int low, int high) {
  if (low >= high) return;
  int pivot = intVec[low];
  int nLow = low + 1;
  int nHigh = high - 1;
  while (nLow <= nHigh) {
    if (intVec[nLow] <= pivot) {
      ++nLow;
    } else {
      std::swap(intVec[nLow], intVec[nHigh]);
      std::swap(matrix[nLow], matrix[nHigh]);
      --nHigh;
    }   
  }
  std::swap(intVec[low], intVec[nHigh]);
  std::swap(matrix[low], matrix[nHigh]);

  iqsort(intVec, matrix, low, nHigh);
  iqsort(intVec, matrix, nLow, high);
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> intVec = {10, 1, 5}; 
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix = {{33.0}, {11.0}, {44.0}};  
  iqsort(intVec, matrix, 0, intVec.size());
  // intVec is {1, 5, 10} and matrix is {{11.0}, {44.0}, {33.0}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that --- when you use some up to date compiler (let's say gcc 4.4 and up) --- there nothing really copied: nowadays objects within C++ standard library containers are (mostly) always moved.  Therefore IMHO there is no need to have any fear about expensive copies.

Have a look at the following example - it was written using gcc 4.4.6 under Debian.  As you can see, during the 'reordering' phase, there is no call to the copy constructor and also no call to the `operator=(... & other)'.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class VeryExpensiveToCopy {
public:
   explicit VeryExpensiveToCopy(long i) : id(i) { ++cnt_normal_cstr; }

   // Just to be sure this is never used.
   VeryExpensiveToCopy & operator=(VeryExpensiveToCopy & other) = delete;
   VeryExpensiveToCopy(VeryExpensiveToCopy & other) = delete;

   VeryExpensiveToCopy(VeryExpensiveToCopy && other) : id(other.id) {
      ++cnt_move_cstr;
   }
   VeryExpensiveToCopy & operator=(VeryExpensiveToCopy && other) {
      id = other.id; ++cnt_op_as_move; return *this;
   }

   long get_id() const { return id; }

   static void print_stats(std::string const & lref) {
      std::cout << "[" << std::setw(20) << lref << "] Normal Cstr [" 
                << cnt_normal_cstr 
                << "] Move Cstr [" << cnt_move_cstr
                << "] operator=(&&) [" << cnt_op_as_move << "]" << std::endl;
   }

private:
   long id;

   static long cnt_normal_cstr;
   static long cnt_move_cstr;
   static long cnt_op_as_move;
};

// Counts the number of calls.
long VeryExpensiveToCopy::cnt_normal_cstr { 0 };
long VeryExpensiveToCopy::cnt_move_cstr { 0 };
long VeryExpensiveToCopy::cnt_op_as_move { 0 };

int main() {
   std::vector<VeryExpensiveToCopy> v;

   VeryExpensiveToCopy::print_stats("Start");
   for(auto i(0); i<100000; ++i) {
      v.emplace_back(i);
   }
   VeryExpensiveToCopy::print_stats("After initialization");
   for(auto i(0); i<100000-1; ++i) {
      v[i] = std::move(v[i+1]);
   }
   VeryExpensiveToCopy::print_stats("After moving");
   for(auto i(0); i<100000-1; ++i) {
      if(v[i].get_id() != i+1) { abort(); }
   }
   VeryExpensiveToCopy::print_stats("After check");

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[               Start] Normal Cstr [0] Move Cstr [0] operator=(&&) [0]
[After initialization] Normal Cstr [100000] Move Cstr [131071] operator=(&&) [0]
[        After moving] Normal Cstr [100000] Move Cstr [131071] operator=(&&) [99999]
[         After check] Normal Cstr [100000] Move Cstr [131071] operator=(&&) [99999]
```