# sort std::vector without losing index info

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

I want to sort a `std::vector` using stored values without losing the index info. For example,

```
std::vector <int> vec;
vec.resize(3);
vec[0] = 20;
vec[1] = 10;
vec[2] = 6;
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
// Here I want to know the order of indices after sort operation which is 2, 1, 0
```

Comment: Perhaps you could create a separate vector of indices and `sort()` that vector with a custom comparator that compares the indexed values rather than the indices themselves?

Comment: Or have a `vector` of `pair`s, where the second element is an `int`, which starts as the index. Then a comparator that just compares on the first element. Not pretty.

Comment: Do you need to sort the elements, or do you want to know the indices of the elements after the sorting, or both?

Comment: If you use the idea proposed by @BoBTFish, I would be careful with declaring `vector< pair<int,int> >`. Make sure you put the space between `>` characters, as I have had problems with certain compilers seeing `>>` as an operator, not the closing of the pair and vector

Comment: @wlyles You must be using a pretty old compiler then! This was strictly mandated by The Standard before `c++11`, but I believe most compilers fixed it years before.

Comment: @BoBTFish yeah, I think we were using an ancient version of g++ for one of my classes. took me forever to figure out what was going on. now I put the space just to be careful

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain the index permutation after the sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554242/how-to-obtain-the-index-permutation-after-the-sorting)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to save the *permutation*  of your original vector, so you need another vector which builds the correct bijection from `{0, ... , n - 1}` to `{0, ... , n - 1}`:

```
vector<unsigned int> permutation( vec.size() );
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    permutation[i] = i;
```

We didn't permutate anything yet. Now you don't sort the second vector, instead you sort the permutation:

```
std::sort(permutation.begin(), permutation.end(), cmp);
```

If you use C++11, `cmp` can be a lambda:

```
[&vec](unsigned int a, unsigned int b) { return vec[a] < vec[b];}
```

If you use C++03 you'll need to use struct with `bool operator()(unsigned int, unsigned int)`:

```
struct comparator{
   comparator(vector& v) : lookup(v){}
   bool operator()(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
       return lookup[a] < lookup[b];
   }
   vector& lookup;
};

comparator cmp(vec);
```

The sorted vector can then be traversed with `vec[permutation[i]]`.

Comment: I always hesitate to use references as members.

Comment: @MooingDuck: True, but would you choose a `vector*` as alternative? A copy could be too expensive.

Comment: If I were doing this, yes, I would have done `vector*` due to that hesitation.  (Not saying my way is better, just that I would have done it that way).  Then my comparitor would be copy/move assignable as just a pointer, whereas yours is not copy/move assignable at all.  OTOH, there's no reason for a comparitor to be copy/move assigned, so there's nothing wrong with your design here.

Comment: @MooingDuck  a member reference of a class is copy-constructible.

Comment: @rwong: right, Zeta's code is copy constructable (and move constructable?), but not copy assignable nor move assignable.  That's what I said.