# How to efficiently sort an array and get the permutation index?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have two random access iterables: one containing the values and the other containing a permutation index. I want to sort the values and track the changes in the permutation index.

Sample input:

```cpp
std::array values{7, 45, 18, 33, 77, 96, 83, 80, 4, 51};
std::array<int, values.size()> index;
```

Output:

```cpp
values == {4, 7, 18, 33, 45, 51, 77, 80, 83, 96};
index == {8, 0, 2, 3, 1, 9, 4, 7, 6, 5};
```

## The simple solution

One solution is to construct a `vector` of `pair`s containing the value and its index,
sort this vector by the values and then extract the solution from this.
But the original vector may be large so I would like to avoid converting it twice.
I will nickname this solution `vector pair sort`.

## Another solution

I can just `std::sort` the permutation index (which would contain 0, 1, 2... in the
beginning) using values in the values iterable. This is described at [How to obtain the index permutation after the sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554242/how-to-obtain-the-index-permutation-after-the-sorting)
This would give me the permutation index but it won't sort the value iterable.
I could do two things from here:

1. `std::sort()` the values.

   I would have to sort the data twice. I would like to avoid that. The comparison operator
   might not be cheap. This solution will be `double sort`.
2. Sort the values using the permutation index.

   I am not exactly sure how to do that. One solution is described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170102-00/?p=95095). This solution
   is `boost index apply sort` (because it is implemented by `boost::algorithm::apply_permutation()`). This modifies the permutation index so I
   have to make a copy before passing it to `boost::algorithm::apply_permutation()`.

   A simple solution that can do it in place is described [here](https://medium.com/@kevingxyz/permutation-in-place-8528581a5553). This is `permutate in place sort`.

   Another solution would be to convert the index into [cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation) and then apply it. I haven't implemented this.

## The "best" solution

I think that the most logical approach is to sort the values normally, but when the
sorting algorithm swaps two values, it should also swap corresponding indexed in
the permutation index.

This would sort both iterables in place at once without any added cost.

But I have no idea how to implement this. If I would be implementing the sorting algorithm,
I could just add a extra `swap()` and the issue would be solved. But I'd like to reuse
`std::sort()`. It gives me a reasonably fast sorting algorithm without the need
of writing it. I could also replace it with a different algorithm in the future by just
replacing `std::sort()` with `custom_sort()` (assuming that `custom_sort()` has same
signature which is a reasonable assumption).

I am interested in `swap()`. `std::sort()` is using this function to swap elements.
My goal is to override this function and to make it swap the actual values and the
indexes.

One way of doing that is creating a custom iterator that would combine iterators
of values and indexes. This iterator would return a reference to a wrapper value upon
calling `operator*` or `operator[]`. This wrapper value would have a custom `swap()`.

## Benchmarks

By the way I have done some benchmarks. You can find them and the implementations at
https://github.com/meator/indexsort_impl I tried to sort a `vector` containing 1 000 000
random `int`s and `double`s. The `int`s are ranging from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` and the `double`s are ranging from 0 to 1. I ran 200 samples. Here are the results:

| function | `int` benchmark | `double` benchmark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value sort* | 114.153 ms | 127.824 ms |
| index sort using values* | 177.985 ms | 206.153 ms |
| vector pair sort | 122.795 ms | 139.467 ms |
| double sort | 291.954 ms | 339.121 ms |
| boost index apply sort | 263.827 ms | 298.844 ms |
| permutate in place sort | 679.917 ms | 708.676 ms |

The "simple" `vector pair sort` is surprisingly good. Maybe the compiler is smart.

## Question

Is my "best" solution with iterators viable? How could I implement that?
Are there some more solutions that I have dismissed? Which is the best?

---

EDIT: My benchmarks contained a massive flaw which invalidated all results. I have fixed that. I also added raw sort benchmarks as per [Paul Sanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5743288/paul-sanders)'es suggestion. These of course aren't indexsort.

* As mentioned above, these aren't actual indexsort.

Comment: The simple solution might be adapted: sort a [zip_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view) (std C++23, use [ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) for previous standard).

Comment: How does `vector pair sort` compare (in terms of execution time) with just sorting the vector of values?

Comment: The pair solution is probably fast because it has good locality of reference; the index and value are right next to each other in memory, probably in the same cache line.

Comment: I have added simple sorting to the benchmarks.

Comment: @user13840624 most of the time cost is in the sorting. So whatever method that allows fast sorting will be the best. It's very likely `vector pair sort` is optimal. You can replace `std::sort` with `highway:: SIMD sort` or `pdqsort` on Github

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution should be doable.  According to [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) one signature until C++20 is

```
template< class RandomIt >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

and after it changes to

```
template< class RandomIt >
constexpr void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

where `class RandomIt` meets the requirement of both [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) and [ValueSwappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ValueSwappable).  Which looks like the iterator can contain an index and pointers to both arrays, implement the right methods, and you have a swap function that takes 2 iterators, and swaps the contents of both functions.

And then you can use `std::sort` with no new large data structures.

Comment: I have tried to do that. But the iterator must be [_ValueSwappable_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ValueSwappable), not [_Swappable_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable) (well it actually has to be _Swappable_ too, but that doesn't help me with indexsort). This means that the value has to be swappable. I not only have to make a custom wrapper iterator, but I also have to make a custom wrapper value. And I have to store this value somewhere. I can't just return it to the caller of `operator*` and `operator[]` because I must return a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your "best" solution is not going to be best, because it does O(N log N) value swaps when only O(N) are required.

I think the actually best option is to sort the indexes using the values, and then reorder the values in O(N) time using the permutation index.

Here's a simple implementation that temporarily inverts entries in the permutation index to mark which value positions we've sorted, and then fixes them all.  When it's finished, both `data` and `index` are correct.

I stole the sort part from @SergeyKalinichenko's answer that you linked:

```
vector<int> index(data.size(), 0);
for (int i = 0 ; i != index.size() ; i++) {
    index[i] = i;
}
sort(index.begin(), index.end(),
    [&](const int& a, const int& b) {
        return (data[a] < data[b]);
    }
);
for (int target = 0; target < index.size(); ++target) {
    int src = index[target];
    if (src < 0) {
        // did this one already
        index[target] = ~src;
        continue;
    }
    if (src == target) {
        //already in the right place
        continue;
    }
    auto save = data[target];
    int t2 = target;
    do {
        data[t2] = data[src];
        t2 = src;
        src = index[t2];
        index[t2] = ~src; // mark t2 position as done. invar: t2 > target
    } while(src != target);
    data[t2] = save;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be what Julia does, e.g., https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/sort.jl#L1814C64-L1814C72