# how to sort class that contains vector<float> type in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I want to sort a class that contains vector type.

For example,

```
class Line
{
public;
vector<float> Angle;
vector<float> Length;
}
```

The angle and length are the line segment's angle and length.

```
Line LineSegment;
LineSegment.Angle.push_back(10.0);   LineSegment.Length.push_back(100.0);
LineSegment.Angle.push_back(20.0);   LineSegment.Length.push_back(50.0);
LineSegment.Angle.push_back(30.0);   LineSegment.Length.push_back(10.0);
```

First line segment has angle of 10 degree and length of 100 pixels.
Second : 20 degree, 50 pixels, third : 30 degree, 10 pixels.

For this example, I'd like to sort by length, so that
the result should have reverse index of original.

How can I do this? I searched several sorting algorithms, however they solved sorting of vectors or classes, or vector that contains class type.

Comment: Is this C++? It seems so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects); it is about sorting a container from the standard library by some user-defined order.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236172/how-do-i-sort-a-stdvector-by-the-values-of-a-different-stdvector

Comment: Its not clear what you mean. Do you have a `vector` of `Line`s that you want to sort? Or do you want to sort segments within a `Line`? Also, I don't understand the sentence "For this example, I'd like to sort by length, so that the result should have reverse index of original."

Comment: Sorry I do not mentioned tool.. I use C/C++!

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++".

Answer (score 3):

It may be more logical to represent a line segment as an object, like:

```
struct LineSegment {
    float Angle;
    float Length;

    LineSegment(float angle, float len) : Angle(angle), Length(len) { }
};
```

And the set of line segments (called "line") as a vector of `LineSegment`:

```
std::vector<LineSegment> line;
line.emplace_back(10.0, 100.0)
line.emplace_back(20.0, 50.0);
line.emplace_back(30.0, 10.0);
```

This groups the "line segments", which should not be split when sorting, like:

```
Angle1 Length1    Angle2 Length2    Angle3 Length3
```

With the code in the answer it is like:

```
Angle1 Angle2 Angle3    Length1 Length2 Length3
```

Then `line` can be sorted as a whole using a comparator function that compares `LineSegment` instances:

```
std::sort(line.begin(), line.end(), [](const LineSegment& a, const LineSegment& b) { return a.Angle < b.Angle; })
// Sorts by ascending angle
```

Comment: That's a good point. OP's design might be motivated by some hardware constraints (eg. whether he wants to parallelize lines processing)

Answer (score 1):

If there is no reason behind the choice of a vector, you could use a regular map:

```
class Line {
public:
    std::map<float, float> segments;
};

Line lineSegment;
lineSegment.segments.emplace(100.0, 10.0);
lineSegment.segments.emplace(50.0,  20.0);
lineSegment.segments.emplace(10.0,  30.0);
for (auto const& seg : lineSegment.segments) {
    std::cout << "Segment of length: " << seg.first << " and angle: " << seg.second << std::endl;
}
```

This will output:

> Segment of length: 10 and angle: 30
>   Segment of length: 50 and angle: 20
>   Segment of length: 100 and angle: 10

Comment: @JonathanWakely I used `insert()` first, forgot to edit it out. I did not use an initializer list to keep OP's convention