# Create training data for CNN

Tags: c++, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data

I have 10 folders and each folder contains images of a certain category/class (typical CNN training data).
I have read in all the folders with containing images, and now I got 10 2D vectors (vector inside a vector).

I am planning on merging all the 10 vectors to 1 big one, and also create 1 vector containing the correct output labels.

But now I am not sure how I can **randomize the 1 vector** containing training data/images and still **keep the correct output labels.**

How can I accomplish the randomization and keep track of the correct output labels?

Comment: You could use a `std::pair<imgae_data, output_tag>`.

Comment: Doing what @NathanOliver said will invalidate the need for an additional vector for the output labels

Comment: I need the additional vector for output labels, because the function I'm using it with expects both vectors.

Comment: see this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236172/how-do-i-sort-a-stdvector-by-the-values-of-a-different-stdvector